# Issue with TestFlight upload API

Tags: testflight

I am using jenkins to automatically upload my build to testflight. I have figured out most of the things I need, but one place I am stuck which I can't seem to get rid of.

This is the script I am using for testflight upload

```
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json \
-F file=@mybuild.ipa \
-F dsym=@mybuilddSYM.zip \
-F api_token='<api_token>' \
-F team_token='<team_token>' \
-F notes='Release notes'
```

I want to provide release notes not a static string, but something more dynamic e.g. my last github commit details, or the latest tag name I created. But I am not able to provide this info.

I tried something like 
-F notes='"$(git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -n 3)"' //to give last 3 commits, but it is taking the "$(git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -n 3)" as a string, and NOT the value.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried surrounding the command with back quotes i.e. ` characters? e.g.

```
notes=`git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" -n 3`
```

The to evaluate:

```
-F notes="$notes"
```

Comment: I do something like this with backticking for the notes field.. works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been working with this script in TeamCity using a shell script. In order for me to use the type of variables like that, I had to use the following syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE_NAME = $( /bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d" )

echo ${VARIABLE_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this with Ruby, especially since fantastic [nomad toolkit](http://nomad-cli.com/) exists!

But there is also this gist for using the shell: https://gist.github.com/djacobs/2411095